# How to send Datetime or Date + Time Parameters in XML via Jasper REST API?

Tags: java, rest, jasperserver

Running Jasper Server 6.1 and I'm utilizing the REST v2 API to schedule and execute reports. However, I'm running into an issue when creating a report with the following inputs:

```
start_date - java.sql.Timestamp
end_date - java.sql.Timestamp
```

I am sending an XML object.

The objective is to send a Datetime or if all else fails, send a separate Date and Time parameters.

I've tried to send the following for java.sql.Timestamp:

- "2019-06-01 21:53:22"
- "2019-06-01 21:53:22.0"
- "2019-06-19 21:29:10.044"
- [epoch in ms and seconds]

For time:

```
- "00:00:00"
```

the xml:

```
<entry>
     <key>end_date</key>
     <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xsi:type="xs:dateTime">[REPLACE with above values]</value>
</entry>
```

Constantly getting the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Timestamp
```